# Check the first checkbox, if no checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_all" value="0" checked /><label for="city_all">All</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_1" value="Chicago" /><label for="city_pref_1">Chicago</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="city_pref[]" id="city_pref_2" value="Texas" /><label for="city_pref_2">Texas</label>
```

And, I have [placed my code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/2/), which is working correctly. What I really want to do is, when none of the checkboxes are selected, then I want the **all** checkbox to get selected automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
       $('#city_all').prop('checked', true)
    }   
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bGwrS/8/)

Comment: thanks Raminson, it is good, but in my case I have a number of checkboxes, for example, one checkbox group for city, one for operating system etc. Can you please modify the code which can work only for particular class or group of checkboxes

Comment: I am really sorry Raminson, as I am disturbing you again, but my fieldset has one more city group with name **name="city_pref_alt[]"**. This is changing the behavious of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0)
         $('#city_all').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is one line ?

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="city_pref[]"]').on('change', function(e){
     this.checked ? $(this).siblings('[name="city_pref[]"]').prop('checked', false) : $("#city_all").prop('checked', true);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bGwrS/22/)